# Does HtmlHelper.RouteLink know about virtual directories?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an issue where I'm generating links for my MVC app in a custom HtmlHelper, and RouteLink isn't aware that the MVC application has a virtual directory. This means I can debug and use the app fine in testing, but it generates invalid links in production. Is there a way to get RouteLink() or ActionLink() to include the virtual directory for the deployed application when links get generated?

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
private const string STagLink = "<span class=\"tag-{0}\">{1}</span>\r\n";
...
MvcHtmlString link = html.RouteLink(x.Name,
   new { Tag = x.Name, Controller = x.Controller, Action = x.Action },
   new { @class = "tag", Title = x.Title });
sb.AppendFormat(STagLink, j, link.toHtmlString());
```

This generates a link like: "/Home/Tag/Production" for the development instance, but when the application is deployed to a virtual directory like /foo, the link is still "/Home/Tag/Production" instead of "/foo/Home/Tag/Production".

This discussion on Phil Haack's blog is similar: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/30/aspnetmvc-refresh.aspx#71053

Is the only solution to set an virtual path for the MVC application at development time? I was hoping MVC would be aware of the context in which it is running.

Comment: `ActionLink` and `RouteLink` certainly do know about virtual folders. We exploit this in production every day. Something is missing here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Craig. I thought the same thing, which is why I'm currently confused why my URLs do not include the virtual folder.

Comment: FWIW, I'm using

    link.toHtmlString()

To get the link text back. Should I be using some other method?

Comment: Also, the machine I'm testing on right now is also one that has Visual Studio on it. All I did to "install" the MVC app was create a virtual directory for it on that machine's IIS web site.

Comment: `ToHtmlString` should be fine. Creating the virtual folder in IIS should be all you have to do. Beware that virtual folders mean you must use `Url.Content`, `Html.RouteLink`, and the like *every time.* Hard-coded, absolute URIs *will* fail.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I'm using Url.Content() and Html.RouteLink() in conjunction with virtualPath() included in this answer above. It turns out I forgot to clean up some test code that was affecting my tag cloud generation, so there isn't any bug. I guess I should withdraw my question, or modify it so that virtualPath() is an answer for the javascript-based url references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean Virtual Application or Virtual Directory? Virtual Directories apply to mapping physical folders to specific "virtual" URL folders. They are sort of orthogonal to ASP.NET MVC. I don't know of any way to run an ASP.NET MVC application "within a virtual directory" as I don't think that makes any sense.

If you're referring to Virtual Applications, then routing does take that into account when an ASP.NET MVC application is running within a virtual application.

Comment: I meant virtual application.

Thanks for the reply, Phil, and for confirming what Craig already told me -- turns out it was a stupid user trick on my part and there wasn't a routelink problem at all.

Comment: I should clarify: Craig didn't call it a stupid user trick. I did ;)